# About minimal complete, consistent extensions of the DLO (dense linear order) theory

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, order-theory

Say we have the theory of DLO, which is not complete, but if we extend it to DLO+NE, where NE is the theory of no endpoint. (aka no maximum and no minimum, for example, the set R), then it is complete.

The question says that there is 5 such kind of minimal extension, I find another one which is DLO + the theory: "there is only one element".

However, I met some problems to find the other 3 extension Xs to make DLO + X be complete. Any clues?

Thanks.

Comment: What's the opposite of *no* endpoints?

Comment: HINT: The other three are similar to $\mathsf{DLO+NE}$; specifically, there are three other possibilities for endpoints besides having none.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott So basically, should I focus on proving 2 endpoints (not the same point), 1 min, 1 max? So plus 2 same endpoint (one point) and no end point, we have 5.

Comment: @qwerty: Exactly. Models of the other three are, for example, $\Bbb Q\cap[0,1]$, $\Bbb Q\cap[0,1)$, and $\Bbb Q\cap(0,1]$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott. Thanks for the help, but after a few hours trying, I do not know how to actually show any of them which is complete. Apparently you've shown some examples to show they are consistent, but about the completeness, how to, generally, show them?

Comment: @qwerty: what tools are you trying to use to prove completeness?